# Asignar formato de fecha con as.POSIXct

Tags: r

Por favor ayudame a comprender la función as.POSIXct

Tengo una base de datos de weatherlink de meteorología y NO logro asignar un formato de fecha y hora a la columna date

> R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

```
meteo$date <- as.POSIXct(strftime(meteo$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
```

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :    character string is not
>   in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Bienvenida Lady M, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] veas [ask] y como crear un [mcve], en cuanto a tu pregunta te sugiero que la edites y agregues una muestra de los que contiene `meteo$date` para poder hacer un diagnóstico más certero. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de como esta definida `date` originalmente.

Si está como texto, como en el ejemplo abajo, no es necesario `strftime`; la conversión puede ser directa:

```
meteo=data.frame(date=c("01/02/2010 10:20", "03/02/2010 15:20", "07/03/2010 01:20", "01/04/2011 12:20"),stringsAsFactors = F)
meteo$date1 <- as.POSIXct(meteo$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

> meteo
              date               date1
1 01/02/2010 10:20 2010-02-01 10:20:00
2 03/02/2010 15:20 2010-02-03 15:20:00
3 07/03/2010 01:20 2010-03-07 01:20:00
4 01/04/2011 12:20 2011-04-01 12:20:00
```